# connect using SSH to server, through corporate SOCKS5 proxy in Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, proxy, git-bash

I am using Windows 10.
I am able to use Putty's proxy section to connect to an external server using a socks5 proxy server with a specified port.
I want to be able to connect this way using Git Bash, with the `ssh` command.
(I don't have access to the `nc` linux command.)

Is there command-line parameter I can add or a property to add to the `~/.ssh/config` file?

Comment: Yes. You should be able to specify that in `ProxyCommand` in `~/.ssh/config`.